# Convert data type object DD-Mon-YYYY to data format in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, strftime, strptime

I've loaded a csv using pd.read_csv in the following format -

```
obj = pd.read_csv('usd_brl_date.csv', sep=';', usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6])

In [34]: obj
Out [34]:
             Date   Price    Open    High     Low Change %
0     18/Mar/2016  3.6128  3.6241  3.6731  3.6051   -0.31%
1     17/Mar/2016  3.6241  3.7410  3.7449  3.6020   -3.16%
2     16/Mar/2016  3.7422  3.7643  3.8533  3.7302   -0.62%

In [35]: usdbrl.dtypes
Out [35]
Date         object
Price       float64
Open        float64
High        float64
Low         float64
Change %     object
dtype: object
```

I need to convert the column Date type object to data type. Or if it possible to set dtype for the first column within pd.read_csv.

Comment: did you try `parse_dates=['Date']` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%b/%Y")

print df
        Date   Price    Open    High     Low Change %
0 2016-03-18  3.6128  3.6241  3.6731  3.6051   -0.31%
1 2016-03-17  3.6241  3.7410  3.7449  3.6020   -3.16%
2 2016-03-16  3.7422  3.7643  3.8533  3.7302   -0.62%
```

[Formats](http://strftime.org/).

Or add parameter `parse_dates` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), as mentioned [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401596/convert-data-type-object-dd-mon-yyyy-to-data-format-in-python/36401738#comment60419803_36401596):

```
obj = pd.read_csv('usd_brl_date.csv', sep=';', usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6], parse_dates=['Date'])

print df
        Date   Price    Open    High     Low Change %
0 2016-03-18  3.6128  3.6241  3.6731  3.6051   -0.31%
1 2016-03-17  3.6241  3.7410  3.7449  3.6020   -3.16%
2 2016-03-16  3.7422  3.7643  3.8533  3.7302   -0.62%
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I set the format at import for the first column even if I don't know its label in file? In this case I have multiple csv files where first columns have different lables but are all same format dates.

Comment: Yes, sure. You can use `parse_dates=[0]`

Comment: Thanks!!! One more if you could help - how can I change the last column Change % to numeric? it should correspond to %.

Comment: I think you can use `df['Change %'] = df['Change %'].str.strip('%').astype(float)`